# TypeError: undefined is not a function but script still loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

So I'm getting this error, even though when looking at the source through chrome, it seems like the jQuery js being loaded and everything, but just not being able to call fdatepicker().

My head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/res/js/foundation-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/res/css/foundation-datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/res/css/foundation.min.css">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The element jQuery is calling:

```
<div class="row date collapse" id="dp" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="small-3 columns" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly>
    <span class="prefix small-2 columns end"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

And my script which has error and is at the bottom of the page before closing the body

```
$(function() {
    $('#dp').fdatepicker();
});
```

I've already tried adding jQuery UI and trying to use Google Chrome's console to call that same function and I still get that error. So it can't be an error with the script calling the element too early or something like that....

Comment: Are you sure that your foundation-datepicker.js have a good path?
maybe try to output a console.log('is loaded');
to make sure that is really loaded.

Comment: does foundation datepicker.js have dependencies like some core.js ?

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond Actually, I just tried console.log('is loaded'); on it, and it didn't seem to load. That doesn't make sense though (for me).... The link points just fine to it when I view the source on chrome.

Comment: @charlietfl I believe the only thing it uses extra is just jQuery, but I think foundation loads that by default if it doesn't see it loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! Found the problem, I was actually loading jQuery once in the header and once all the way down where the footer was, but I couldn't see it because I'm using jsp to include a footer file, and inside there was where I loaded jQuery.

So the main thing is: just don't load the same script twice, and make sure to look in places that might be hidden, especially if you're using jsp to include stuff from other files.

Answer (score 0):

**Do following**

1 . View source of page(ctrl+U). And then click on link of each script. If now you are not able to see the source of script means, script path is wrong.

2 . Check console for exact error or any script conflict.

Comment: far easier to look for bad paths in network tab of console without having to click on source

Comment: The only thing the console says is that TypeError. All the links are also pointing fine.

Comment: @charlietfl all links seem to also be good under the network tab. They all have 200 or a 304 on them. Datepicker js is also loaded and the console has no errors.

Comment: @charlietfl  In my past experience  sometime it was hard to explain where user can find console and how to use it.

So i used simple method here

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your fdatepicker is not properly loaded.

Try to insert this script:

```
 <script src="http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/js/foundation-datepicker.js"></script>
```

And if it's works, it is because your path is not good.

**EDIT:**

I have make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XL7vZ/) with your code..

All should be works.

I have insert this script:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/js/foundation-datepicker.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/stylesheets/foundation-datepicker.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
```

and it's works.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that too, and it still doesn't work. All the links are also pointing correctly (I went through the source and clicked through all the links, and they all point properly).

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it still isn't working when I insert that code, it still doesn't work, even though it's working on JSFiddle....

Comment: you have something you break your JS.
you can try to insert your <script>$(function() {
    $('#dp').fdatepicker();
});</script> just before your <script scr="foundation...">

Comment: Aha! Found the problem, I was actually loading jQuery once in the header and once all the way down where the footer was, but I couldn't see it because I'm using jsp to include a footer file, and inside there was where I loaded jquery.